# How do I get a table from postgresql to be saved as a csv file in python running in airflow?

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, psycopg2

Apologies in advanced if the structure of the question is messy, as it is my first post here.

I have this code below that runs without error if done in a code cell (Jupyter notebook), but when I tried using this code in the python file with DAG to run in airflow, it just gets stuck in ***status: up for retry***.

Note that the connections and everything have been added to airflow, and the code *does* work separately, just not when implemented into airflow/DAG.

---

I have tried running these:

**Note: I am using psycopg2 as db here.**

```
def FetchPostgresql():
    '''
    Fetch data from Postgresql
    '''
    conn_string="dbname='postgres' host='localhost' user='postgres' password='' port='5433'"
    conn=db.connect(conn_string)
    df=pd.read_sql("select * from my_table", conn)
    df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

I have also tried using the Hook method as I browsed through stack overflow, but it also just gets stuck at ***status: up for retry***.

```
def work_with_postgress():
    hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="postgres_default", schema="postgres")
    df = hook.get_pandas_df("SELECT * FROM my_table")
    df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

As for the default args, this is the code:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'name',
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2023, 11, 20, 23, 30), 
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=15),
}
```

and this is the DAG code:

```
with DAG('Test',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=60),      # '0 * * * *',
         ) as dag:

    fetchData = PythonOperator(task_id='fetch',
                                 python_callable=work_with_postgress) # Tried with FetchPostgresql

    copyFile = BashOperator(task_id='copy',
                                 bash_command='cp /folder_path')


fetchData >> copyFile
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39I0Q.png)

Is there a fix to this? Or perhaps a different method? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: 1) *...using psycopg2 as db here...* is not correct. Postgres is the database, psycopg2 is the client/driver. 2) Have you looked at the Postgres log to see what is hitting the database? There could be an error that is being swallowed by the code.